# Parse and strip quotes from json objects

Tags: json, jchartfx

My data

```
var data = [
{"title":"2013-12-09", "calls_in":"345", "calls_out":"100"},
{"title":"2013-12-08", "calls_in":"125", "calls_out":"97"}, 
{"title":"2013-12-07", "calls_in":"85", "calls_out":"2"},
{"title":"2013-12-06", "calls_in":"185", "calls_out":"22"},
{"title":"2013-12-05", "calls_in":"74", "calls_out":"419"}
]
```

arrives from a PHP script in json format as above. I'm using an API namely 'jChartFX', it's basically a javascript graphing library that makes cool charts on the fly with javascript/jquery.

Currently using the data above the library fails to parse it. It fails due to the quotes around the integer values. I need the data to in the format:

```
var data = [
        {"title":"2013-12-09", "calls_in":345, "calls_out":100},
        {"title":"2013-12-08", "calls_in":125, "calls_out":97}, 
        {"title":"2013-12-07", "calls_in":85, "calls_out":2},
        {"title":"2013-12-06", "calls_in":185, "calls_out":22},
        {"title":"2013-12-05", "calls_in":74, "calls_out":419}
    ]
```

you see, the integers are NOT wrapped in quotes. How can i do this using jQuery or javascript.

In it's most basic form (working) the full script would look something similar to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="chartfx.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jchartfx.system.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jchartfx.coreBasic.js"></script>  
</head>
<body onload="loadChart()">
<div id="ChartDiv" style="width:600px;height:400px"></div>
<script>

var chart1;

function loadChart(){        

    chart1 = new cfx.Chart();
    chart1.getData().setSeries(2);
    chart1.getAxisY().setMin(0);
    chart1.getAxisY().setMax(700);

    var series1 = chart1.getSeries().getItem(0);
    var series2 = chart1.getSeries().getItem(1);

    series1.setGallery(cfx.Gallery.Lines);
    series2.setGallery(cfx.Gallery.Lines);

    var data = [
        {"title":"2013-12-09", "calls_in":345, "calls_out":100},
        {"title":"2013-12-08", "calls_in":125, "calls_out":97}, 
        {"title":"2013-12-07", "calls_in":85, "calls_out":2},
        {"title":"2013-12-06", "calls_in":185, "calls_out":22},
        {"title":"2013-12-05", "calls_in":74, "calls_out":419}
    ]

    console.log(data);
        chart1.setDataSource(data);
        var divHolder = document.getElementById('ChartDiv');
    chart1.create(divHolder);            

  }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: just call `parseInt()` in the JavaScript on each integer value before passing the data to jChartFX.

Option 2: If you can modify the PHP script, encode your JSON like this: `json_encode($arrayContainingTheData, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK );`

Example of option 2:

```
$x = array( 'foo' => "1", 'bar' => "2");
echo json_encode($x, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK  );
```

Result: `{"foo":1,"bar":2}`

More info:

- http://www.php.net/json_encode -- explains `json_encode()`
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php -- explains the `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` constant

Comment: echo json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); worked a charm. Thanks.